Chrome third-party cookie restrictions - reCAPTCHA Enterprise
Will reCAPTCHA Enterprise be affected by Chrome third-party cookie restrictions on Q3 of 2024?
REF : https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd
We did a test for breakage by enabling chrome://flags/#test-third-party-cookie-phaseout and it seems to work.
REF: https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/prepare/test-for-breakage
No need for CHIPS?
REF: https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/chips

Disclaimer: I'm a reCAPTCHA team member.
reCAPTCHA continues to work without third-party cookies. We've long been preparing for this transition. No need to do anything special. See the following:
https://github.com/privacysandbox/privacy-sandbox-dev-support/blob/main/3pcd-readiness.md
